# How to count total time of column state for the given status

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql I have a table **device** with column for timestamp(long) and for status(boolean):

```
| ts   | status |
+------+--------+
| 1    |      1 |
| 2    |      1 |
| 5    |      1 |
| 17   |      0 |
| 18   |      0 |
| 26   |      0 |
| 31   |      1 |
| 32   |      1 |
| 37   |      1 |
```

Need a query to count how long the status was 1.
For the given case it is: `(17-1) + (37-31) = 22`

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? do you have 8.0.2 an above?

Comment: I use it on Ubuntu, the version is 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Isn't it 5 - 1 ?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: the number is unknown and it can grow

Comment: If you have a big table, I recommend to add a `position` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your device table

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e27644/1

**First step** create a view `ordered_status` *(mysql doesn't support window function like rank ;-( )*

*(You can skip this view by adding a `position` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` directly in your `device` table)*

```
create view ordered_status as
select   
    count(*) position,
    A.ts,
    A.status    
from
    device A
    left join device B on
        A.ts >= B.ts
group by
    A.ts,A.status
```

**Second step**, join each row with the next and compute only timestamp delta for `status=1`, and `sum` the total :

```
select
    sum(case
    when A.status=1 then B.ts-A.ts
    else 0   
    end)        
from
    ordered_status A
    left join ordered_status B on 
        A.position+1 = B.position
```

**Or without view** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97b97/1

```
select
    sum(case
    when A.status=1 then B.ts-A.ts
    else 0   
    end)        
from
    (select count(*) position, A.ts,A.status    
       from device A left join device B on A.ts >= B.ts
      group by A.ts,A.status) A
    left join 
    (select count(*) position, A.ts,A.status    
       from device A left join device B on A.ts >= B.ts
      group by A.ts,A.status) B on 
        A.position+1 = B.position
order by
    A.position
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not use window function, the solution is slightly more complicated

```
select sum(final.ts * final.sign)
from
(
    select device.ts,
           case when status = 1 and (prevstatus is null or prevstatus = 0) then -1  else 1 end sign
    from
    (
        select d1.ts, d2.status, prev.ts prevts, prev.status prevstatus, next.ts nextts, next.status nextstatus
        from (
          select d1.ts,
               d1.status,
               max(d2.ts) prevts
          from device d1
          left join device d2 on d1.ts > d2.ts
          group by d1.ts, d1.status
        ) d1 
        left join (
          select d1.ts,
               d1.status,
               min(d2.ts) nextts
          from device d1
          left join device d2 on d1.ts < d2.ts
          group by d1.ts, d1.status
        ) d2 on d1.ts = d2.ts
        left join device prev on prev.ts = d1.prevts
        left join device next on next.ts = d2.nextts
    ) devicePrevNext
    where (status = 1 and (prevstatus is null or prevstatus = 0 or nextstatus is null)) or
          (status = 0 and prevstatus = 1)
) final
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e1273c8ac5adb84e8c4f57313ae46a67)

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as "getting the next 0" and using that information for the sum:

```
select next_ts_0, min(ts) as ts_1, max(ts) as ts_1_end
from (select d.*,
             (select d2.ts
              from device d2
              where d2.status = 0 and d2.ts > d.ts
              order by d2.ts asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_ts_0
      from device d
     ) d
where status = 1
group by next_ts_0;
```

Then you can add up the results:

```
select sum(coalesce(next_ts_0, ts_1_end) - ts_1)
from (select next_ts_0, min(ts) as ts_1, max(ts) as ts_1_end
      from (select d.*,
                   (select d2.ts
                    from device d2
                    where d2.status = 0 and d2.ts > d.ts
                    order by d2.ts asc
                    limit 1
                   ) as next_ts_0
            from device d
           ) d
      where status = 1
      group by next_ts_0
     ) d;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d364c6/7) is the SQL Fiddle for this solution.

An index on `device(status, ts)` might help.  If performance is an issue, you might need a solution using variables.